# PHPUnit sound notification on test completion or failure

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpunit, phpstorm

I notice that I start procrastinating when waiting for test result. And to stop myself from it is quite challenging so I thing little sound notification would be really nice way of solving this issue.

I use PhpStorm for development and running test. It would be nice to have a plugin that would play a sound on test failed/completion or a way how to integrate a bash script after test completion in PhpStorm I see only this option to add some condition before test but not after.

[image]

Comment: Try [Grep Console](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125-grep-console) plugin -- it has an option to play custom sound when it sees certain stuff in the output (the rule based -- you would need create RegEx-based rule(s) that would recognize successful and failed builds).

Comment: Other than that (no idea if they work though): 1) https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11498-execution-sounds 2) https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6100-console-beep or check all results: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/search?products=phpstorm&search=sound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Notifications` you can use the `Play sound` checkbox to play the system alert or "bell" sound for any specific notification you choose.  Select the notification entry `Test execution finished` in the list and enable `Play sound`, and it will play the sound when a test has finished.